# Converting a string to a class in Swift

Tags: swift, objectmapper

I am using Alamofire to make a GET request and am using the ObjectMapper library to convert the response into its own class in Swift.

```
Alamofire.request(self.REST_METHOD!, self.REQUEST_URL, headers : ["Authentication_Token" : authToken]).responseJSON { response in


    if response.response != nil && response.response?.statusCode == 200 {

        let json = JSON((response.result.value as? NSDictionary)!)
        let classType : AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString(entityType)!  as AnyObject.Type                
        //let model =  Mapper<classType>.map(json.rawString())


    }
}
```

The entityType variable can be one of many types i.e. User, Student, Teacher, Staff, etc. I am trying to dynamically create a class type and create the model based on that.

However it crashes on the line `let classType : AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString(entityType)!  as AnyObject.Type` giving the error message:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Also when I uncomment the line `let model =  Mapper<classType>.map(json.rawString())`, it gives me a compiler error:

> classType is not a type

What is wrong with the above code

Comment: Why do you believe something is wrong with this code? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: Sorry, added more details

Comment: what is entityType ?

Comment: the reason for the fatal error is that NSClassFromString(entityType) returns nil. the reason for the second (compiler) error is that AnyObject is protocol. to see his type use AnyObject.self which gives you AnyObject.Protocol.

Comment: @Roee84 In this example, entityType is Student. And the name of the project is University

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Because NSClassFromString is failing and returning nil, which then you are unwrapping, thereby causing the error.

I'm guessing that `entityType` contains a class name along the lines of `myClass`. Swift now uses namespaces, so to create a class from a string, the string must contain `AppName.myClass`.

You could either hardcode your app name, or use the following code to get it:

```
    NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"] as! String
```

There are other problems with your code too. When NSClassFromString succeeds, it will create an instance of the class. This cannot be cast to a type. Also, you can't pass a variable as a generic in `Mapper<classType>`, as Swift needs to know the class type at compile time. Instead you could change the Mapper class to take the type as a parameter. For example:

```
    Mapper.map(classInstance.dynamicType, json.rawString())
```

Although now that I re-read your question, you're using a library for Mapper, and are therefore probably reluctant to change it.

And looking at the doco for ObjectMapper, it needs you to create a Mapper instance - ie. instead of `Mapper<MyClass>.map` you need `Mapper<MyClass>().map`.

Comment: I tried hardcoding it (for testing purposes) `let classType : AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("University.Student")!  as AnyObject.Type
                print (classType)`, but when I try to print out class type, it gives me `classType = <Unable to determine byte size.>`

Comment: I got the first part working i.e. I have a valid classType

Comment: The class however is a subclass of Object (as I am using RealmSwift), so I am not able to use classType.type

Comment: Oops, it should have been `dynamicType`.

Comment: I have an error message that says: `Argument labels (_:,_:) do not match available overloads